# Change Http.get Url and show again in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have url that returns data 
I read data with angular

```
  var appModule;
(function () {
    appModule = angular.module('Ryka', []);
    appModule.controller('TaskControler', ['$scope', '$http', function (scope, http) {
        scope.mytask = mytask;
        http.get('http://localhost/_vti_bin/RykaSolution/RykaService.svc/MyOverDueTasks/first').success(function (data) {
        scope.Tasks = data}).error(function (err) { alert(err) })
    }]);
})();
```

i want to change http.get url using ng-click ... this code executes when the page loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this (simplified example):

```
(function () {
    var appModule = angular.module('Ryka', []);

    appModule.controller('TaskControler', ['$scope', '$http', function (scope, http) {
        scope.tasks = undefined;

        $scope.getTasks = function (type) { 
            http.get('http://localhost/tasks/' + type).success(function (data) {
                scope.tasks = data
            }).error(function (err) { 
                // Handle error
            })
        }

        // Initial loading of data.
        $scope.getTasks("overdue");

    }]);
})();
```

Just a little bit of explanation. Calling `$scope.getTasks("overdue")` would result in the URL like this:

```
http://localhost/tasks/overdue
```

You could then call the same method from your view like this:

```
<a ng-click="getTasks('current')">Get my current tasks</a>
```

which would result in a such URL:

```
http://localhost/tasks/current
```

I hope you got and idea.

PS: You would be better off by moving `getTask` method into a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).